# nodejs profiling; what can 'Unknown' be

Tags: node.js, profiling, v8

While profiling a nodejs program, I see that 61% of the ticks are caused by 'Unknown' (see below). What can this be? What should I look for?

gr,

Coen

```
Statistical profiling result from node, (14907 ticks, 9132 unaccounted, 0 excluded).

 [Unknown]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   9132   61.3%

 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   1067    7.2%    0.0%  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
     55    0.4%    0.0%  C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll

 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   1381    9.3%   10.0%  LazyCompile: *RowDataPacket.parse D:\MI\packet.js:9
......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a 64 bit version of Node.JS to run your application and a 32bit build of the d8 shell to process your `v8.log`. 
Using either a 32 bit version of Node.JS with ia32 as the build target for the d8 shell or a 64 bit version of Node.JS with x64 as the d8 shell build target should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you loading any modules that have built dependencies?

Basically by "Unknown" it means "unaccounted for" (check `tickprocessor.js` for more explanation). For example, the GC will print messages like "scavenge,begin,..." but that is unrecognized by `logreader.js`.

It would help to know what profiling library your using to parse the `v8.log` file.

**Update**

The `node-tick` package hasn't been updated for over a year and is probably missing a lot of recent `prof` commands. Try using [node-profiler](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler) instead. It's created by one of node's maintainers. And if you want the absolute best result you'll need to build it using `node-gyp`.

**Update**

I've parsed the `v8.log` output using the latest from [node-profiler](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler) (the latest on `master`, not the latest tag) and posted the results at http://pastebin.com/pdHDPjzE

Allow me to point out a couple key entries which appear about half way down:

```
[GC]:
  ticks  total  nonlib   name
  2063   26.2%

[Bottom up (heavy) profile]
6578   83.4%  c:\node\node.exe
1812   27.5%    LazyCompile: ~parse native json.js:55
1811   99.9%      Function: ~<anonymous> C:\workspace\repositories\asyncnode_MySQL\lib\MySQL_DB.js:41
 736   11.2%    Function: ~Buffer.toString buffer.js:392
```

So 26.2% of all script type was spent in garbage collection. Which is much higher than it should be. Though it does correlate well with how much time is spent on `Buffer.toString`. If that many Buffers are being created then converted to strings, both would need to be gc'd when they leave scope.

Also I'm curious why so much time is spent in `LazyCompile` for `json.js`. Or more so, why would `json.js` even be necessary in a node application?

To help you performance tune your application I'm including a few links below that give good instructions on what to do and look for.

Nice slide deck with the basics:
https://mkw.st/p/gdd11-berlin-v8-performance-tuning-tricks/#1

More advanced examples of optimization techniques:
http://floitsch.blogspot.com/2012/03/optimizing-for-v8-introduction.html

Better use of closures:
http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html

Now as far as why you couldn't achieve the same output. If you built and used [node-profiler](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler) and its provided `nprof` from `master` and it still doesn't work then I'll assume it has something to do with being on Windows. Think about filing a bug on GitHub and see if he'll help you out.

Comment: I'm using the npm 'tick' package

Comment: I've tried using https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler, but the outcome remains the same.

Comment: @coen Can you pastebin or something your v8.log file. It'd be the easiest way for me to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build v8 with profiling support on:

```
scons prof=on d8
```

Make sure you run `node --prof` with version corresponding to version of v8

Then `tools/linux-tick-processor path/to/v8.log` should show you the full profile info.

Comment: scons has been deprecated now in favour of gyp.